# jQuery $.post request always pending on Chrome on Android phone

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, google-chrome

I have a strange issue which does not make sense, but, given symptoms, maybe someone more experienced can throw in a couple of ideas.

**IN SHORT**

- Specs: PHP5.5 + Apache2 + jQuery2.1 + Semantic-UI2 + Chrome on Android (latest)
- Tried on different devices one of which I'd like to focus on was LG G3
- There's a login page and upon submission request does not go through. The status shows "pending" and debugger takes you to an xhr.send(...) line inside the jquery.js as if it's stuck there. No JS errors whatsoever. After some time request times out and cancels itself.

**LONGER EXPLANATION**

- The whole problem starts at the login screen. Login page loads fine the first time. Entering username + pass and clicking "Login". The Network tab in Chrome dev tools shows that request was initiated but is stuck now and doesnt go through.

Here's a screen:

[image]

Here's a snippet of jQuery code where it all gets stuck

```
xhr.onload = callback();
xhr.onerror = callback("error");

// Create the abort callback
callback = xhrCallbacks[ id ] = callback("abort");

try {
 // Do send the request (this may raise an exception) 
 xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null ); // ===> IT HAPPENS HERE!
} catch ( e ) {
 // #14683: Only rethrow if this hasn't been notified as an error yet
 if ( callback ) {
  throw e;
 }
}
```

- Secondly, im trying to refresh the page now and it doesnt. It's now stuck permanently
- No errors on JS, and since request didnt go through no errors on PHP either.
- In fact it seems that some elements might also get stuck being loaded using jQuery's `$.get` or `$.post`. And it seem to happen exclusively on Android with Chrome. Firefox worked fine anyways.